# Confluent.Kafka.ProduceException`2: 'Broker: Message size too large'

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I try to publish a message that is over 4 MB to Kafka, but I get the exception Confluent.Kafka.ProduceException`2: 'Broker: Message size too large'.

Kafka is running in docker.
Here is a Kafka configuration from a docker-compose file:

```
kafka:
     image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
     ports:
       - 9092:9092
     environment:
       KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
       KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
       KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
       KAFKA_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE: 10000000
       KAFKA_MAX_MESSAGE_BYTES: 10000000
```

But when I start a container I see in logs:

```
kafka_1       |INFO ProducerConfig values:
kafka_1       |         max.request.size = 1048576

kafka_1       | [2019-10-09 13:04:48,146] INFO KafkaConfig values:
kafka_1       |         message.max.bytes = 1000012
```

It means that passing variables KAFKA_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE and KAFKA_MAX_MESSAGE_BYTES doesn't work for confluentinc/cp-kafka image. Although, the documentation doesn't say that it's possible.

In my application I create a producer using the following ProducerConfig:

```
var config = new ProducerConfig
{
   BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
   ReceiveMessageMaxBytes = 10000000,
   MessageMaxBytes = 10000000,
}
```

But I still get the exception.

So what is the right way of increasing default max message size?

Comment: message.max.bytes would be set by `KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES`. The request size is a producer config, not a broker config

Comment: Where in Confluent files does one set these properties?